Converting a pyproject.toml into a Poetry pyproject.toml
I am new to using Poetry and wanted to convert a pyproject.toml used in a repo that uses pyenv-virtualenv and pip to instead use pyenv and Poetry. I am using Python 3.12.2 and Poetry version 1.8.3, and pyenv 2.3.36-21-g7e550e31.
To provide you with some context, I can share the original and the adapted pyproject.toml:
Original pyproject.toml
[project]
dependencies = [
    "weave>=0.50.9",
    "openai>=1.12.0",
    "ollama>=0.1.7",
    "itsdangerous>=2.0.1",
    "peewee>=3.0.0",
    "fastapi>=0.111.0",
    "uvicorn>=0.22.0",
    "fastapi-sso>=0.10.0",
    "boto3>=1.34.67",
]
name = "openui"
version = "0.4.0"
description = "A backend service for generating HTML components with LLM's"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.8"
authors = [{ name = "Chris Van Pelt" }]
license = { text = "Apache-2.0" }
classifiers = ["License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License"]

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["openui", "openui.util"]

[project.urls]
Homepage = "https://github.com/wandb/openui"
Changelog = "https://github.com/wandb/openui/releases"
Issues = "https://github.com/wandb/openui/issues"
CI = "https://github.com/wandb/openui/actions"


[project.optional-dependencies]
test = ["pytest", "pre-commit"]
litellm = ["litellm[proxy]>=1.40.20", "google-generativeai"]
eval = [
    "beautifulsoup4>=4.0.0",
    "mistletoe>=1.0.0",
    "Pillow>=8.3.1",
    "playwright>=1.41.0",
]
tui = ["textual[syntax]>=0.49.0", "pyperclip>=1.8.2"]


Adapted for Poetry
[tool.poetry]
name = "openui"
version = "0.4.0"
description = "A backend service for generating HTML components with LLM's"
authors = ["Chris Van Pelt <email@example.com>"]
license = "Apache-2.0"
readme = "README.md"
homepage = "https://github.com/wandb/openui"
repository = "https://github.com/wandb/openui"
documentation = "https://github.com/wandb/openui"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.8"
weave = ">=0.50.9"
openai = ">=1.12.0"
ollama = ">=0.1.7"
itsdangerous = ">=2.0.1"
peewee = ">=3.0.0"
fastapi = ">=0.111.0"
uvicorn = ">=0.22.0"
fastapi-sso = ">=0.10.0"
boto3 = ">=1.34.67"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^6.0"
pre-commit = "^2.0"

[tool.poetry.extras]
litellm = ["litellm[proxy]>=1.40.20", "google-generativeai"]
eval = [
    "beautifulsoup4>=4.0.0",
    "mistletoe>=1.0.0",
    "Pillow>=8.3.1",
    "playwright>=1.41.0",
]
tui = ["textual[syntax]>=0.49.0", "pyperclip>=1.8.2"]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"


After I attempted to convert the pyproject.toml and tried to poetry install, I encountered this error:
❯ poetry install

The Poetry configuration is invalid:
  - data.extras.litellm[0] must match pattern ^[a-zA-Z-_.0-9]+$

If I comment out the [tool.poetry.extras] section, the poetry install works. I've tried looking at Poetry's documentation and it doesn't explain how to implement this particular type of setup using lists. Does anyone know the correct way to convert this type of pyproject.toml so that it works as expected when you use poetry install -E <extra dep>?
Thank you for your help.

The section of the docs you linked explicitly explains how to specify optional dependencies, along with extras in dependencies (like litellm[proxy] and textual[syntax]). Which part is not clear?

Thanks for your response. What I don't understand is how to declare litellm in the format the documentation specifies if it is expected to be an array. When I change the brackets to curly braces and attempt to use the specified format, it tells me this:
The Poetry configuration is invalid: - data.extras.litellm must be array

The version constraints and needed extras have to go under [tool.poetry.dependencies] along with optional = true, and then the package names go in an array under [tool.poetry.extras].
